# Django SiteTree: menu renders but breadcrumbs doesn't when variable is in url

Tags: django, django-sitetree

I am using django==1.11 and django-sitetree==1.9.0, all links without url variables render both on menu and breadcrumbs but urls with variables only render on menu(with correct links) and not on breadcrumbs.

```
Title: {{ object.title }}
URL: products:detail object.slug object.pk
URL as Pattern: Checked
```

---

```
url(r'^products/(?P<slug>[-\w\d]+)~(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.ProductDetailView.as_view(), name='products:detail)
```

---

```
{% sitetree_breadcrumbs from "main-menu" template "sitetree/breadcrumbs_semantic.html" %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with `~` sign in the url pattern, by changing the url pattern from

```
url(r'^products/(?P<slug>[-\w\d]+)~(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.ProductDetailView.as_view(), name='products:detail)
```

to

```
url(r'^products/(?P<slug>[-\w\d]+)-(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.ProductDetailView.as_view(), name='products:detail)
```

I could fix the problem.